# Run angular PWA on mobile

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, httpserver

I turned my angular project into a pwa as described on https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

When I start the server with

> http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/

only the

> http://127.0.0.1:8080

seems to be working and offers me to install the PWA.
When I try to access

> http://192.168.xxx.xx:8080

there seems to be an issue with the secure origin, so I can't install the PWA.

any hints what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong per se, One of the [Requirements](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) for making a PWA installable is by serving it over (https),

And for development purposes the browser considers `(127.0.0.1:)` and `(localhost:)` to be secure domains, But other customised domains are not recognised, hence are treated as development servers that are not secured. You should stick to 127.0.0.1 for the time being since it works, until you move to your potential Live secured server!

Comment: Thank you for the helpful reply! So in my understanding there is no way to try it out on my mobile phone with accessing (192.168.xxx.xx) until im Live?

Comment: Well yeah, if you're having no live server, you could consider checking [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/)

Comment: If its something simple, you might consider pushing it to a free HTTPS host like glitch for quick testing of A2HS.